# I can't use the blit method in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, attributeerror, blit

I'm following a tutorial on youtube for building a platformer with pygame. 
I'm getting the error: Traceback(most recent call last):
File I:\Home\PYGAME\main.py line 23 in 
screen.blit(player_image, player_Pos)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' Object has no attribute 'blit'

How do I solve this?

Here's my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
SCREEN_SIZE = (500,500)

screen = pygame.display.set_caption('first pygame project')
pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE, 0, 32)

moving_Right = False
moving_Left = False
player_Pos = (50,350)
velocity = 10
player_y_momentum = 0

running = True

player_image = pygame.image.load('I:\Home\PYGAME\player_icon.png')

while running:
    screen.blit(player_image, player_Pos)
    if moving_Right == True:
        player_Pos[0] += velocity
    if moving_Left == True:
        player_Pos[0] -= velocity

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moving_Right = True
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moving_Left = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moving_Right = False
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moving_Left = False
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: From the error, `screen` is not set to anything. Not usre pygame, so not sure what that initialisation line does or how it is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this part:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_caption('first pygame project')
pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE, 0, 32)
```

To this:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE)
pygame.display.set_caption('first pygame project')
```

What you have done does not allow you to use screen as an object.